# How to return some popup or message or alert when file is not created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a action method

```
public ActionResult Export(int? protocol, int? visitno)
{
    //creating file here
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvData))
    {
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvData), "text/csv", "Sample.csv");
    }
    if(no file created)
    {
        //need to do something 
    }
}
```

if no file is created in the method i should show some message in the same page like popup, alert or anything.
i tried setting view bag and showing the message not worked well... what i can do here?

what should i return to show some message?

Comment: You can return your message in content like`return Content("some message");`

Comment: I think you can use `if(no file created)` to `else` thats it.

Comment: Add your view page code.

Comment: view page only has one link to download

Answer (score 3):

You can do is like below, In your controller action,

```
public ActionResult Export(int? protocol, int? visitno)
{
    //creating file here
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvData))
    {
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvData), "text/csv", "Sample.csv");
        TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Your success message here";        
    }

    if(no file created)
    {
       TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Your error message here";
    }
}
```

Then you can add it to your view as, (Assume that you are using bootstrap)

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["ErrorMessage"].ToString()))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Alert! </strong>@TempData["ErrorMessage"].ToString()</div>
}
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["SuccessMessage"].ToString()))
{
    <div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success! </strong>@TempData["SuccessMessage"].ToString()</div>
}
```